# CucumberBackendException: No test instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-spring

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.1 (but same happens with 2.6.4) project using Cucumber BOM 7.4.1.

```
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.4.1"))
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-spring'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit-platform-engine'
```

My entry point is :

```
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameters({
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "my.project.cucumber"),
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "@Dwh"),
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "long"),
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true"),
    @ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "json:build/cucumber/cucumber.json")
})
public class RunCucumberDwhTest {

}
```

My glue code :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = DwhE2EApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DwhE2EApplication.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DwhStepDef implements En {

  ....
}
```

When running the Cucumber tests, I get this error :

> io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: No test instance
> at
> app//io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.notifyTestContextManagerAboutAfterTestMethod(TestContextAdaptor.java:129)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.stop(TestContextAdaptor.java:109)
> at app//io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.stop(SpringFactory.java:159)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.disposeBackendWorlds(Runner.java:156)
> at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:78)    at
> app//io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$4(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:112)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:129)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:129)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:109)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.PickleDescriptor.execute(PickleDescriptor.java:100)
> at
> app//io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.PickleDescriptor.execute(PickleDescriptor.java:29)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@17.0.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@17.0.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteLauncher.execute(SuiteLauncher.java:59)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestDescriptor.execute(SuiteTestDescriptor.java:130)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestEngine.lambda$execute$0(SuiteTestEngine.java:73)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestEngine.execute(SuiteTestEngine.java:73)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
> at
> app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at
> org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at
> org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
> at
> org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
> at
> app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at
> app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No test instance  at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)     at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getTestInstance(DefaultTestContext.java:160)
> at
> io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.notifyTestContextManagerAboutAfterTestMethod(TestContextAdaptor.java:125)
> ... 89 more

I can see in the logs that my Spring Context gets loaded, the in-memory DB gets bootstrapped... it fails after.

In debug mode, I see that the Given/When/Then steps are captured, so my feature file is found for sure.

Actually, it seems to fail when Cucumber performs some cleanup after a step executes :

at some point in `io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor` , we have this method that gets called :

```
private void notifyTestContextManagerAboutAfterTestMethod() {
    try {
        Object delegateTestInstance = delegate.getTestContext().getTestInstance();
        Method dummyMethod = TestContextAdaptor.class.getMethod("cucumberDoesNotHaveASingleTestMethod");
        delegate.afterTestMethod(delegateTestInstance, dummyMethod, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CucumberBackendException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

it's the  `delegate.getTestContext().getTestInstance()` that throws the exception, as the `testInstance` is null.

any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigations in debug mode, I finally understood. I believe it's a change brought in the 7.4.1 cucumber version, as it's not happening in previous versions. I've reported it here : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2584

Basically, my glue code is throwing an exception when it gets instantiated. But the exception is not caught by Cucumber, and instead a quite unrelated error message gets logged.

I understood this when I realized I was not entering the code defined for the steps in my glue code class. Then, I realized I was entering the glue code constructor, but an exception was thrown from there.  And this exception gets swallowed silently by Cucumber, which drove me in the wrong direction for longer than expected.